# Blog posts not trimmed evenly in list - and sometimes at first period

Tags: nodes

The list of blog posts on my D7 site should display posts trimmed to 300 letters, but some posts simply stop at the first period "." Without an eclipse or anything. If I remove the period - and put ANYTHING else - it works fine. Is there a setting somewhere to cut a post at a period within the trim limit or something?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This similar post may be of help: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28643/drupal-7-teaser-trim-ends-after-first-p-tag-how-can-i-make-it-continue